# Automating First Parameter of COUNTIF Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help automating the `COUNTIF` function. 
My data is organized like a corresponding x/y values chart (Table 1):

| Hours |  |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 6 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 1 |

I want to get a count of how many of a certain number there are under a certain category, like this (Table 2):

| Hours | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

I'm using a `COUNTIF` function to automate that. However, I'll be using many different Table 1's and they may not all have the same number of 0 hours and 1 hours, etc.

For example, Table 2 is created by using `COUNTIF($L4:$L5,J125)` and `COUNTIF(L6:L22,J125)`. However, I want the first parameters of `COUNTIF` to change by corresponding to whether there is two 0's in Table 1's Hours column or less/more. Is there a convenient combination of functions to do that or should I just reorganize the data from Table 1 into separate tables?

Keep in mind, this data is only a short segment of the whole data. There are up to 20 hours and also more categories than just the one shown.

Comment: What version of excel are you using. Newer versions have the formula `=Unique()` and the ability to spill the results into other cells allowing you to specify an array as the criteria in the countif formula.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want help with?  Do you want help with generating the first column of Table 2 (i.e., hours 0 and 1)?  (Rather than just using 0 through 23?)  Do you want help with generating the first row of Table 2 (i.e., the numbers 1 through 7)?  You say there are more categories; what does that mean?  Do you want to have Table 3, Table 4, Table 5, etc?  Or do you want Table 2 to be bigger?  (What should it look like?) … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Please be clear that what is next to Hour in Table 1 and their relationship,,, better [edit] your post & upload proper data with us along with expected output the criteria to count and avoid Down votes to close the post!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10=$E2)*($B$2:$B$10=F$1))
```

[image]

Comment: smart move @Lee but still in not clear whether second column in in tagged with first or not,, anyways +10 ☺

Comment: Thank you, I can't upvote this due to not having enough rep. but I would if I could. From my (limited) understanding, this works because you are multiplying two conditions that return true (1) or false (0) values. It's basically two if statements.
ex. If the Table 1 hours/data column corresponds to the Table 2 columns.
Then the SUMPRODUCT simply just sums all the multiplication products (basically a bunch of 0's or 1's).